# What do the words ("SheTishreh" & "Milfanecha") mean?

Tags: hebrew, song-poetry

What do the words ("SheTishreh" & "Milfanecha") mean? Do they have a source in Tanach?

I found them in Avraham Fried's song "Matzliach".

Yehi ratzon milfanecha
Shetishreh shechinah
bema’asey yedeichem

Comment: I edited your question slightly to add a request for the source, otherwise it would be [off-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Rashi says this was Moshe's blessing in the verse ([Shemot 39:43](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.39.43?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

> And Moses saw all the work, and, behold, they had done it; as Hashem had commanded, even so had they done it. And Moses blessed them.

Milfanecha = in front of you

Shetishreh = may it rest (or stay)

It means
`May it be Your will that Hashem's presence rest on the work of your hands`

Answer (score 1):

[mbloch's answer](/a/68371) answers most of your question, but not the

> Do they [=the words "SheTishreh" and "Milfanecha"] have a source in Tanach?

part. So I'll address that here.

מלפניך / *mil'fanecha*, "from before you", is from the noun פנים, "face/front", which appears numerous times in *Tanach*. The form *mil'fanecha* appears I think ten times (Ex. 23:28; Deut. 9:4, 28:31, 31:3; Ⅱ Sam 7:15; Jer. 18:23; Ps. 17:2, 51:13; Neh. 3:37; Ⅰ Chr. 29:12).

שתשרה / *shetishre*, "that it imbue", is from a root שרה that as far as I can tell does not appear in *Tanach*.

Comment: Thank you, msh210.... But, I need to know what is the Latin transliteration of  שרה?

Comment: @Refoeini, the one I wrote? It's a [root](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_root), not a word, so isn't pronounced, so has no transliteration.